# Any way to get JSON data of a Google Doc SpreadSheet using jquery without make the doc public?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to get data from a Google Doc Spreadsheet, using javascript and jQuery, in order to do some math with the numbers.

With the next code I got it, for public spreadsheets:

```
function getdata( key, wid, f )
{
    return $.getJSON(
        '//spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/' +
         key + '/' + wid + '/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=?',
            function( data ){
                    /* the content of this function is not important to the question */
                    var entryidRC = /.*\/R(\d*)C(\d*)/;
                    var retdata = {};
                    retdata.mat = {};
                    for( var l in data.feed.entry )
                    {
                            var entry = data.feed.entry[ l ];
                            var id = entry.id.$t;
                            var m = entryidRC.exec( id );
                            var R,C;
                            if( m != null )
                            {
                                    R = new Number( m[ 1 ] );
                                    C = new Number( m[ 2 ] );
                            }
                            var row = retdata.mat[ R ];                                                                                                                           
                            if( typeof( row ) == 'undefined' )                                                                                                                    
                                    retdata.mat[ R ] = {};                                                                                                                        
                            retdata.mat[ R ][ C ] = entry.content;                                                                                                                
                    }                                                                                                                                                             
                    if( typeof( f ) != 'undefined' )                                                                                                                              
                            f( retdata )                                                                                                                                          
                    else                                                                                                                                                          
                            console.log( retdata );                                                                                                                               
            }                                                                                                                                                                     
    );
}
```

When tried for private ones, I got the data in XML (using the URL:
`'//spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/'+ key + '/' + wid + '/private/basic'` ). This test checks also for the availability, the firewall, the permission setup and the login state of the current user.

But adding the last part: `?alt=json-in-script&callback=f` to get the data in JSON, throws an *Not found, Error 404*. (Also got if only `alt=json` is added).

Summary of situation:

```
       public     private
XML     yes         yes
JSON    yes       Question
```

The use of *JSON against google* is described in http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/gdata/docs/json.html

The use of *google spreadsheet api* is described in
http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/reference.html#WorksheetFeed

**Any way to get JSON data of a GDoc SpreadSheet using javascript without make the doc publicly available?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is my first question, please vote/comment in order I can improve my style

Comment: Presumably `&callback=f` is a typo, and you mean `&callback=?`

Comment: when I am in the address bar of a browser, I use `=f`, from jquery I use `=?`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "Note: Retrieving a feed without authentication is only supported for published spreadsheets." ~~ http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! At least I can stop searching. Please, post an answer, so I can accept it and mark the question as solved, since it will be useful to somebody in the future.

Comment: thanks @robermorales your comment about XML gave me some hope; could you share more details on how did you manage to get XML feed out of a private spreadsheet using $.getJSON() ? -- thanks, Fausto

Comment: @FaustoR. I don't get the XML using getJSON, I did using the address bar of the browser for url testing purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"[Note: Retrieving a feed without authentication is only supported for published spreadsheets.](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample.html)"

Shame, because this would be a very useful feature.  As it is, I'm pleased to learn that this is possible at least from published docs.